# How to create a 2D overlay over a 3D game? (LWJGL/OpenGL)

Tags: opengl, java, lwjgl

GameDev!

I would like to create a 2D overlay over a 3D world, using LWJGL (Java version of OpenGL), to show information to the player, for example, a chat box, health bar, selected cannonball type, etc.

Currently the code I have is this (Taken from several sources on the internet):

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0.0f, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight(), 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        glDisable(GL_BLEND);
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
            glVertex2f(0, 0);
            glVertex2f(1, 1);
            glVertex2f(1, 0);
            glVertex2f(0, 1);
            glEnd();
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();
            glPopMatrix();
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
             glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
                glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
                glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
                glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
             glDisable(GL_BLEND);
                GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
                GL11.glLoadIdentity(); // Reset The Projection Matrix
                GLU.gluPerspective(45.0f, ((float) Display.getWidth() / (float) Display.getHeight()), 0.1f, 5000.0f); // Calculate The Aspect Ratio Of The Window

                GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
                glLoadIdentity();
```

However this does not show a 2D scene at all!

I would appreciate it if anybody could help me.

Thanks!

Comment: The glOrtho call should be done on the projection matrix.

Comment: @Ben Sorry to be stupid, but what do you mean by "On" the projection matrix?
Thanks!

Comment: When you call glMatrixMode it sets the current matrix that will be use in subsequent opengl matrix function calls. A glOrth call sets up an orthographic matrix( what you need for a 2D scene ) on the current matrix. In this case your glOrtho call is being done on the modelView matrix. You want it to be done on the projection matrix. Move the glOrth line up right before GL11.glMatrixMode( GL11.GLMODELVIEW );

Comment: @Ben I have done that but I still dont have anything rendered. Updated code is in the original post.